# How to get the content in Talk pages of wikipedia in python

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, pywikibot

I am currently using the following code to obtain the page content of wikipedia.

```
import pywikibot as pw

page = pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'Forensic science')
page.text
```

However, it seems like the above code does not reaturn content in `Talk pages` of wikipedia. e.g.,

```
import pywikibot as pw
page = pw.Page(pw.Site('en'), 'Talk:Forensics science')
page.text
```

More precisely, I want to get the content of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Talk:Forensic_science&action=edit

I am happy to provide more details if needed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the talk page title. `'Talk:Forensics science'` should have been `'Talk:Forensic science'` (without the `s` at the end of `Forensic`). Other than that it should work as you expect.

If you want to get an explicit error when the page does not exist try the `Page.get` method:

```
import pywikibot as pw
page = pw.Page(pw.Site('en', 'wikipedia'), 'Talk:Forensics science')
text = page.get()
```

this will raise:

```
[...]
"...site.py", line 4166, in loadrevisions
    raise NoPage(page)
pywikibot.exceptions.NoPage: Page [[wikipedia:en:Talk:Forensics science]] doesn't exist.
CRITICAL: Exiting due to uncaught exception <class 'pywikibot.exceptions.NoPage'>
```

Comment: And you can use `talkpage = page.toggleTalkPage()` to get talk page object from a page one you already have, without hardcoding the `Talk:`.